# Copy folder from current directory to parent folder in bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to copy a folder(.husky) from current path to parent folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get parent folder:
parent_folder=$(cd ../ && pwd)
# Trying to copy folder called `".husky"` into parent folder:
cp .husky $parent_folder/test1
```

But I am getting error saying:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can get the parent dir like this: `parent_folder="${PWD%/*}"`

Comment: How is `git` getting involved with this?  Perhaps you should post the whole script.

Comment: @TimRoberts The is the whole script. Attached screenshot

Comment: @kittu the `PWD/*` looks strange. Did you try my approach below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the parent folder, track first the current folder of your script, assuming .. is relative to where your script is:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$(readlink "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" )" && pwd )"
parent_folder=$(cd "${DIR}" && pwd)
echo "parent_folder='${parent_folder}'"
```

Then add `set -x` in the first lines of your script to see where it triggers the "`not a git repository`" error message.

---

The [OP kittu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1800583/kittu) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429605/copy-folder-from-current-directory-to-parent-folder-in-bash/67429863#comment119185461_67429863):

> Actually I had `git` alias setup previously where `cp` is `alias cp='git commit -p'`, hence the `git` error.
> Its working fine now.

Comment: Thank you so much. You help me identifying the issue with `set -x`. Actually I had git alias setup previously where `cp` is `alias cp='git commit -p'` hence the git error. Its working fine now.

Comment: @kittu Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.